# Close tab in Chrome after certain amount of time for a specific URL

Tags: chrome

We have an application that unbelievably doesn't have a user inactivity time out. We have a limited amount of concurrent licenses. I am looking for a way to automatically close the tab for users (using chrome) after a specific amount of time of inactivity (10 mins), but only for a specific domain/URL.  I realize this is a very specific request, but thought I would ask. There is an extension called tab wrangler for Chrome but it does not allow you to restrict the behavior only to a specific domain/URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome aboard, Jason. I like this question and have starred it as a favo(u)rite, so I hope that you get an answer. If you do not, can you code? Selenium, which is used to test browsers apps (or similar test app, but Selenium is the most popular) could be used to create a script to do this for you.

Comment: An alternative closing that single tab would be to dedicate a browser to that app and another for everything else. Then you have generalize the problem to closing an app after a given time. It ought to be easier to find an app to do that. If not, [AutoIt]( https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) would make it easy to script it on Windows. Options are fewer for Linux, but they do exist.